# How to extract information using BeautifulSoup from a particular site

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My objective is to extract info from site https://shopopenings.com/merchant-search after entering **pin code** of the respective area and copy all info from there. Whether outlet is opened or closed. There has to be loop.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As far as I know BeautifulSoup only parses HTML, so there is no way of entering a zip code with it. I'd recommend using an API for this instead

Comment: Can we do with selenium then?

Answer (score 1):

This site has an underlying API that you can use to get JSON responses. To find the endpoints and what is expected as request and response you can use the [Mozilla developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and [Chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) under network.

```
import json
import requests

SEARCH_ADDRESS = "California City, CA 93505"

urlEndpoint_AutoComplete = "https://shopopenings.com/api/autocomplete"
urlEndpoint_Search = "https://shopopenings.com/api/search"

search_Location = {"type":"address", "searchText":SEARCH_ADDRESS, "language":"us"}

locations = requests.post(urlEndpoint_AutoComplete, data=search_Location)

local = json.loads(locations.text)[0] # get first address
local["place_address"] = local.pop("name") # fix key name for next post request
local["place_id"] = local.pop("id") # fix key name for next post request

local["shopTypes"] = ["ACC", "ARA", "AFS", "AUT", "BTN", "BWL", "BKS", "AAC",
 "CEA", "CSV", "DPT", "DIS", "DSC", "DLS", "EQR", "AAF", "GHC", "GRO", "HBM",
 "HIC", "AAM", "AAX", "MER", "MOT", "BMV", "BNM", "OSC", "OPT", "EAP", "SHS",
  "GSF", "SGS", "TEV", "TOY", "TAT", "DVG", "WHC", "AAW"]

local["range"] = 304.8
local["language"] = "us"

results = requests.post(urlEndpoint_Search, data=local)
print(json.loads(results.text))
```

```
{'center': {'latitude': 35.125801, 'longitude': -117.9859038},
 'range': '304.8',
 'merchants': [{'mmh_id': '505518130',
   'latitude': 35.125801,
   'longitude': -117.9859,
   'shopName': 'Branham M Branham Mtr',
   'shopFullAddressString': 'California City, CA',
   'isOpen': False,
   'nfc': False,
   'shopType': 'AUT',
   'distance': 0.34636329,
   'country': 'USA'},
  {'mmh_id': '591581670',
   'latitude': 35.125442,
   'longitude': -117.986083,
   'shopName': 'One Stop Market',
   'shopFullAddressString': '7990 California City Blvd, California City, CA 93505-2518',
   'isOpen': True,
   'nfc': True,
   'shopType': 'AFS',
   'distance': 43.04766933,
   'country': 'USA'},
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: That's pretty helpful. Can you please help how this could be iterate over others locations and converted into DF or into CSV.

Comment: To get other locations change `SEARCH ADDRESS` accordingly, this will result in multiple suggestions in `locations` variable. How you gonna deal with multiple address suggestions is up to you to define. To transform the JSON result in DF or CSV you can use `Pandas` library and follow the documentation [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: I have further query to search via pin/address and merchant name both at the same time. How it can be done. If you can some links that would be great help.

Comment: As stated in the answer all endpoints (and their parameters) can be found by inspecting the network tab the moment a search is performed. To search for the address and merchant name at the same time you would need to add the merchant's name to the `local` dictionary passed to the `resquest.post` (e.g. `local["merchant_name"] = "Dimaggio's Olde Time Pizza"`).

Answer (score 0):

I think use selenium to control the Navigation and the entering of the Pin then use BeautifulSoup to work with the Page Source after you action. Here is the documentation it's easy enough to get you started.

Selenium -- https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

BeautifulSoup -- https://readthedocs.org/projects/beautiful-soup-4/

Enjoy!!